# Ajax select2:select event doesn't work when selecting something

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

My problem is select2:select event doesn't fire, when user is selecting something. Though if you trigger event manually(with $('#select2').trigger('select2:select') method), it works. I have no idea, what's wrong, cause it should not be wrong.

Select2 version:  3.5.2

This is how i generated a select2 with Ajax:

```
var obj1 = $('#div89').select2({
  minimumInputLength: 2,
  closeOnSelect : true,
  multiple: true,
  //minimumResultsForSearch: -1,
  //cache: true;
  ajax: {
    quietMillis: 1000,
    url: function (params,page) {
      //returns URL with search params and page
    }
    },
  cache: true,
  data: function (params, page) { },
  results: function (data,page,term) { 
    var more = (page * 50)>1 ;
    var myrez = [];
    var node;
    var i=0;
    var j=data["length"];
                 
     if (j<50) {more=false};
     if (term.term!=""){ more=false};
        data.map(function (item) {
       var c=item["id"];
                           
       var NotesAddress=item.NotesAddress;
       var MainDepartment=item.MainDepartment;
                    
       var c1=item.text+"("+item.MainDepartment+")";
       var name=item.text;
                            
                    
       node = {
              'id': name,
              'text': c1, 
              'NotesAddress': NotesAddress, 
              'MainDepartment' : MainDepartment, 
              'name' :name

           } ; 
    i=i+1;
    myrez.push(node)
                                                                        
   });
   return { results: myrez, more: more };
 },
           
 }
});
```

And this is event i am binding to this select 2:

```
$(function() {
        $('#div89').on('select2:select', function(e) {

            var d = $("#div89").select2('data');
    
            console.log('ddddd -> ', d, e);
            
            var elemDopSogl1 = document.getElementById("inputTextAddCoordT");
            var elemDopSogl2 = document.getElementById("naAddCoord");
            
            var a2 = "";
        
            var a4 = "";
            
            for (var i = 0; i <= d.length - 1; i++) {
                if(i == 0) {
                    a2 += d[i].name;
                    a4 += d[i].NotesAddress;
                } else {
                    a2 = a2 + "; " + d[i].name;
                    a4 = a4 + "; " + d[i].NotesAddress;
                }
            }
        
        
            elemDopSogl1.value=a2;
            elemDopSogl2.value=a4;
        });
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: just make 'onchange' event on select2-container instead of 'select2:select'.

```
$('#div89').on('change', function(e) {
  //do something
}
```